# Conditional Java Parsing - Getting Child Node Contents

Tags: java, dom

I am having some problems with what should be simple DOM parsing. I have checked over numerous questions and so far nothing has helped my situation. The problem is that I have some conditional nodes that may appear in an XML or may not appear. The tool that I have created must save the contents of these values into ArrayLists to be used later. Here is the XML in question:

```
-<Dbtr>

   -<PstlAdr>

      <AdrLine>111 Arlington Ave</AdrLine>

      <AdrLine>Apartment A</AdrLine>

      <AdrLine>Augusta, AZ 11100</AdrLine>

   </PstlAdr>

</Dbtr>
```

Specifically, the Dbtr tag may appear any number of times in an XML. For each Dbtr tag there may be between 1-4 AdrLine children. I need to be able to save the value of each AdrLine and if there is no value then save a blank "" value into the array list for each.

To do this I wrote the following code:

```
NodeList Dbtr = doc.getElementsByTagName("Dbtr");
        for(int i = 0; i < Dbtr.getLength(); i++){

            NodeList DbtrChildren = Dbtr.item(i).getChildNodes();
            if(DbtrChildren.getLength()==1){
            //Add the first child.  
            }else if(DbtrChildren.getLength()==2){
            //Add the first & second child.
            }else if(DbtrChildren.getLength()==3){
            System.out.println("Test Flag");
            System.out.println(DbtrChildren.item(0).getNodeValue()+"Node Value");
            System.out.println(DbtrChildren.item(0).getAttributes()+"Text Attributes");
            System.out.println(DbtrChildren.item(0).getTextContent()+"Text Content");
            }else if(DbtrChildren.getLength()==4){
            //Add all 4 children.   
            }

        }
```

So depending on the number of children AdrLine nodes the values will either be saved into an array list or else a blank value will be saved.

The problem is that no matter what I do I get blank values for the children. I can clearly see during testing that the Dbtr tag does in fact have 3 children. As you can see I tried to do some debugging to figure out some way to get the values. See results below:

```
Test Flag

                                Node Value
nullText Attributes

                                Text Content
```

So I'm getting a large amount of whitespace but no value. Of course I considered that perhaps it was actually picking up "PstlAdr" but then why would it successfully detect 3 child nodes?

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution to my problem.

In the above example I was getting back "3" for the length of DbtrChildren which led me to believe that the three children elements were the adrline tags.

In reality the three children were #text, pstladr and #text (the #text apparently represents the /n).

So I was trying to get values from a tag without values. Once I tried

```
for(int i = 0; i < Dbtr.getLength(); i++){

                NodeList Dbtr2 = Dbtr.item(i).getChildNodes();

                Node Dbtr3 = Dbtr2.item(1);

                System.out.println(Dbtr3.getNodeName());


                }
```

I got back "Pstladr" as the result so now I know I only need to go further into "Pstladr" to fix my problem.